# C++ - What underlying type would an enum with more than 18,446,744,073,709,551,616 elements have?

Tags: c++

This is more of a hypothetical question than a practical one. Of course there would be memory issues if we actually tried to compile a program with that large.

Enums in C++ will take on an underlying type to fit the maximum element of the enum. Also, if I specify no integer values, then each element is always 1 more than the previous starting at 0. So, for example, if I make an enum with 5 elements(or labels, however you call them) then it's type could be something like an int since that can fit the values 0,1,2,3,4.

The largest integral type in C++ is the long long, and an unsigned long long can take a value of up to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615. So what would happen if I made an enum with 18,446,744,073,709,551,616 elements? This would exceed the largest integral type, so it would need another type than long long.

What does the C++ spec have to say about this loophole?

Comment: By the time that code finishes compiling, the language spec will have been updated and we'll all be running on 128-bit systems and driving flying cars.

Comment: I believe the standard says if no integral type can represent all the enumerator values then the enumeration is considered ill-formed. Loophole closed?

Comment: Ah but no literal can hold that value. There is no way to assign an enum value to 18,446,744,073,709,551,616

Comment: `enum foo { bar = 18446744073709551615, baz };`

Comment: Try that and you will see that foo::bar isn't actually 18446744073709551615. If you did printf("%d", foo::bar) it would print something else.

Comment: Well, that depends on the size of `int`, doesn't it. You're using `%d`. Why are you using `printf` at all in a C++ question... is my question.

Comment: You may ask the compiler: https://godbolt.org/z/W681c9ndP

Comment: printf is still used in c++.

Comment: Yes, but you need to know how to use it. You're passing an unsigned 64-bit value with specifier for a signed integer. Why not try `std::cout << (std::uint64_t)foo:bar` at least.

Comment: You make a good point. Interestingly enough, your example enum does compile. It seems that gcc makes it into an unsigned int 128

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no loophole. You'll just get a diagnostic in a conforming compiler.

> [dcl.enum]
>
> [7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.enum#7.sentence-2) ... If no integral type can represent all the enumerator values, the enumeration is ill-formed. ...

Or more practically, you'll get an error and compilation will halt.

It might even halt sooner, due to implementation defined limits, because that's *a lot* of enumerators.